Yeshiva style learning
Firstly I want to clarify that this is NOT personal advice, so I will respect rule Number 1 of MY.
What I expect is this becoming an information post with sources for people who may be on this same situation (I think there's no problem on doing this)
So here's the question: How should one who never attended Yeshiva learn? i.e not what books or time schedule which has already been dealt with here What should a Jew learn regularly? . What I’m referring to is actual enjoyment and commitment to Torah, especially for people who come from a not very frum background.
For those who say that Torah itself is the enjoyment I understand where you come from, as Koheles 11:7 says, that Torah is "a sweet light".
However not everyone reaches this level, so does anyone have any source that deals with this? I think commitment is one of the keys to Torah learning.
To be more precise as @shmosel noted, I'm not refering to seeing results which in cases like Halacha are pretty evident, I'm talking more in enjoying the study itself on subjects which may be not of the personal enjoyment of the talmid, i.e some gemara's maseches or learning gemara itself as learning alone makes it harder.
As this is my second question I hope I didn't make any mistake. In case I did I’m more than happy to edit the post or do whatever Is necessary.
Thank y'all.

@shmosel I may expressed myself wrong, what I mean Is not seeing the result, it's more focused on enjoying the process.

Rambam mishnah Torah is a good place to start. There is much more but this allows you to go through every single topic in halacha and is readily available in English as well as many shiurim that can be listened to as well. Best of success to you.
